# how to convert numbers upto 63 digits into word in python?

Tags: python

i want to convert numbers into words in python without importing any module or library

i already tried to make some code, but when so many zeroes are present between then it is not working properly

```
print("upto sixty three digits only: ")
a=input("enter the number: ")
c=a
e=int(a)
b=""
l=[]
l2=[]
while len(c)%3 != 0:
    c="0"+c
d=len(c)/3
while len(c)!=0:
    l.append(c[0:3])
    c=c[3:len(c)]

on=["", "one","two","three", "four","five","six","seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]

tens=["","","twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

h="hundred"
grt=["thousand","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion","nonillion","decillion","undecillion","duodecillion","tredecillion","quattuor-decillion","quindecillion","sexdecillion","septen-decillion","octodecillion","novemdecillion","vigintillion"                                        ]

for i in l:
    k=int(i)

    if i[0]=="0":
        if k<20:
            l2.append(on[k])
        else:
            l2.append(str(tens[k//10])+" "+str(on[k%10]))
    else:
        if int(i[1:3])<20:
            l2.append(str(on[k//100])+" "+h+" "+str(on[k%100]))
        else:
            l2.append(str(on[k//100])+" "+h+" "+str(tens[(k%100)//10])+" "+str(on[k%10]))


for i in range(0,len(l2)):

    b=b+l2[i]+" "+grt[int(d-2)]+" "
    d=d-1
l=b.split()
l.pop()
d=""
for i in l:
    d=d+i+" "
print(d)
```

while entering the numbers with no zeroes in between the code is working properly

(Eg. 123456789=>one hundred twenty three million four hundred fifty six thousand seven hundred eighty nine)

but it is not working good when there are many zeroes in between

(Eg. 120000000987=>one hundred twenty billion million thousand nine hundred eighty seven)

Comment: It seems you just have to say, that if you have for example 0 millions to not print the millions.

Will look in more detail at your code

Comment: yes @gelonida you are right

Comment: can you help me to sort it out @gelonida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is one if statement:
Just write instead of the simple

```
b=b+l2[i]+" "+grt[int(d-2)]+" "
```

an if statement to not add the grt wortd if the value is "" (0)

```
if l2[i] != "":
    b=b+l2[i]+" "+grt[int(d-2)]+" "
```

Just some extra suggestions:
What's easier for coding / testing is to declare a function, then you can call your function against some 'test patterns' and change / improve your code until all tests are OK.

Below you see an example of your code transformed to a function and a few lines testing both examples, that you posted in your question.

I had to add one more line to make the test pass.
I removed a trailing blank character with the line:

d = d.strip()

Look at below code:

```
def num2txt(num):
    a = num
    c=a
    e=int(a)
    b=""
    l=[]
    l2=[]
    while len(c)%3 != 0:
        c="0"+c
    d=len(c)/3
    while len(c)!=0:
        l.append(c[0:3])
        c=c[3:len(c)]

    on=["", "one","two","three", "four","five","six","seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]

    tens=["","","twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

    h="hundred"
    grt=["thousand","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion","nonillion","decillion","undecillion","duodecillion","tredecillion","quattuor-decillion","quindecillion","sexdecillion","septen-decillion","octodecillion","novemdecillion","vigintillion"                                        ]

    for i in l:
        k=int(i)

        if i[0]=="0":
            if k<20:
                l2.append(on[k])
            else:
                l2.append(str(tens[k//10])+" "+str(on[k%10]))
        else:
            if int(i[1:3])<20:
                l2.append(str(on[k//100])+" "+h+" "+str(on[k%100]))
            else:
                l2.append(str(on[k//100])+" "+h+" "+str(tens[(k%100)//10])+" "+str(on[k%10]))


    for i in range(0,len(l2)):
        if l2[i] != "":
            b=b+l2[i]+" "+grt[int(d-2)]+" "
        d=d-1
    l=b.split()
    l.pop()
    d=""
    for i in l:
        d=d+i+" "

    d = d.strip()
    return d

print("upto sixty three digits only: ")
# a=input("enter the number: ")
test_data = [
    ("123456789", "one hundred twenty three million four hundred fifty six thousand seven hundred eighty nine"),
    ("120000000987", "one hundred twenty billion nine hundred eighty seven"),
    ]

for num_str, expected in test_data:
    result = num2txt(num_str)
    if result == expected:
        print("OK", repr(num_str), "=", repr(result))
    else:
        print("KO", num_str, "=>", repr(result), "!=", repr(expected))
```

Comment: something failed during my copy / paste
This time the code is really  transformed to a function and two 'tests' added

Answer (score 0):

As @gelonida suggested, it would be much better if you used functions to do the "dirty job". As an example, I modified your script adding two functions, one for dividing the number in chunks of length 3, and a second for "wordifying" aferomentioned chunks. Like this I believe that the code gets simpler, shorter and way more readable:

```
def wordify(n):
    s=''
    if len(n)==3:
        s+=on[int(n[0])]+' hundred '
    if len(n)>1:
        if n[-2]=='1':
            s+=teen[int(n[-1])]
            return s
        else:
            s+=tens[int(n[-2])]+' '
    s+=on[int(n[-1])]
    return s

a=input('Insert number: ')
gb3 = lambda x: [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(x),3)]
rem = len(a)%3
tokens=[a[:rem]]+gb3(a[rem:]) if rem!=0 else gb3(a[rem:])
l = len(tokens)

on=["", "one","two","three", "four","five","six","seven", "eight", "nine"]
teen=["ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]
tens=["","","twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
grt=["","thousand","million","billion","trillion","quadrillion","quintillion","sextillion","septillion","octillion","nonillion","decillion","undecillion","duodecillion","tredecillion","quattuor-decillion","quindecillion","sexdecillion","septen-decillion","octodecillion","novemdecillion","vigintillion"]

print()
word_number = ''
for k in range(l):
    if int(tokens[k])!=0:
        word_number += wordify(tokens[k])+' '+grt[l-k-1]+' '
print(' '.join([w for w in word_number.split(' ') if len(w)>1]))
```

The bit in the last print call I made it as a quick way to evenly space the words.
Tell me what you think about it!